# Delete from ListBox items in a Loop

Tags: vb.net

Each Item information get from a file which specified with the name of that item. Even though the selected items will be deleted properly in the listbox but the file of next item will be deleted. I don't know if problem is for Index or anyother part

```
  SourceDir  = "c:\"
  For Each itemIndex In listHouse.SelectedIndices()
            itemIndex = listHouse.SelectedIndices(0)
            listHouse.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex)
            MsgBox(listHouse.Items.Item(itemIndex).Text & "R.txt")
            File.Delete(SourceDir & listHouse.Items.Item(itemIndex).Text & "R.txt")

        Next
```

Comment: you cannot delete/remove stuff in a FOr/Each loop indexed on that thing.  when you RemoveAt, you change the constituency of the loop

Comment: What exactly are you asking...?

Comment: As user delete an item from the list, the file specified to that item also delete with that

Comment: that is understood, but you cant delete from the list (removeAt) then try to use that removed item in the FileDelete step, and you cannot delete from a loop using For/Each because you change what you are looping on.  (After you RemoveAt, itemIndex points to a different item!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add or remove items from a collection while inside a `For/Each` loop.

Each time you `RemoveAt(n)`, you change the make-up of the collection you are looping.  If you remove item #4, item 5 moves up to its slot.  Then after `Next`, your code will be looking at position 5, and be looking at what was originally #6 - item 5 would be skipped entirely.  To prevent this every-other one bug/issue, an exception is thrown when using a `For/Each`.

Secondly, your `File.Delete` code is trying to reference the item you just removed!

To iterate a collection and remove some/all items one by one, loop backwards using an indexer.  This removes from the end of the collection so nothing can "move up".  Like this:

```
' loop backwards using For n
For n as Integer = listHouse.SelectedIndices.Count -1 to 0 Step-1
    itemIndex = listHouse.SelectedIndices(n)

    MsgBox(listHouse.Items.Item(n).Text & "R.txt")
    File.Delete(SourceDir & listHouse.Items.Item(n).Text & "R.txt")

    ' also remove the thing AFTER you have used it to delete
    listHouse.Items.RemoveAt(n)
Next
```

If you tried to use a forward `For n` loop with this sort of action, you'd get the every-other one issue.

Comment: But I use that loop to delete not only one item bu as much as user selected. So is there anyway that to add this option as well?

Comment: @EmPlusPlus it is the same loop doing the same thing, just looping differently. not sure what you are asking.